# How to make a search and filter using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, events

So I am trying to make a Photo filter search. I am able to get to the keyup function but then get stuck on how to search and select the paragraph text. I can not alter the HTML and can only add Javascript.

And what I have so far in my Javascript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

  const query = document.querySelector('#filter');

  let images = document.querySelector('.thumb-display');


    query.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        let search = query.value;


         for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            let searchVal = images[i].getElementByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;

            if (searchVal.indexOf(search) > -1) {
                images[i].display = "";

            } else {
                images[i].display = "none";
            };
        }; 

    });


  })// NO CODE OUTSIDE OF HERE
```

I want to be able to search the (for example) #oceanbeach #mountainroad

text and have the images that don't go with the search to be hidden but I can't get it to work.

Comment: im guessing u have to select the images by whats listed in the p tags class

Comment: the instructions online say The user will be able to enter any partial search text in the filter textbox and have the page
automatically update the display (with each key press) to only display photo thumbnails that have a
partial match for any associated tags. With each key press, any photos that do not have a partial match
of the text must be hidden from the display; use the included hidden CSS class to hide/unhide elements.

Comment: When there is a value present in the filter control, the reset link must become visible. Clicking the reset
link should clear the filter, all thumbnails should become visible, and the rest link should become hidden
again. Your solution must take into account that there may be any number of thumbnails currently in 
the gallery. You will need to implement an event handler for a new type of event: input

Comment: also im not allowed to edit the html

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is the input event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event and this is the click event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: so far ive got window.addeventlistener() im really new to this and don't have a plethora of knowledge on this stuff just started trying to self learn it but i learn most from when im able to visualy see the code and break it down but this has me stumped ive seen some other examples on the web but they all use jquery

Comment: Can you update your post to show us what you've got so we can help you out?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the content and hope that gives more information on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event for the textbox and loop through the `p` tags to show/hide the `.thumb-display`.

```js
const txtFilter = document.getElementById('filter');
const lnkReset = document.querySelector('.reset');
const thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-display');
const tagContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.tags');

txtFilter.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const filter = e.target.value;

  if (filter === '') {
    resetFilter();
  } else {
    // Show the reset link/button.
   lnkReset.classList.remove('hidden');
  
    tagContainers.forEach(tagContainer => {
      const thumbnail = tagContainer.closest('.thumb-display');
      const tags = tagContainer.innerText;
      
      if (tags.indexOf(filter) >= 0) {
       thumbnail.classList.remove('hidden');
      } else {
       thumbnail.classList.add('hidden');
      }
    });
  }
});

lnkReset.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  resetFilter();
});

function resetFilter() {
  thumbnails.forEach(thumbnail => thumbnail.classList.remove('hidden'));
  lnkReset.classList.add('hidden');
  
  txtFilter.value = '';
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

img {
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="frm-filter">
    <div class="frm-group">
      <a class="reset hidden" href="#">Reset</a>
      <input class="frm-control" type="text" id="filter" name="filter" placeholder="tag filter" />
    </div>
  </form>
</nav>
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#africa #mountain #road</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#palmbeach #distantpeaks</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#oceanbeach #mountainroad</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#lake #clearskies #onthewater</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#fallcolors #bridgecrossing #river</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#fallcolors #slowdown</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#falltrees</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#ontheroad #falldriving</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#mountainflowers #clouds #river</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#mountainlake #retreat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#stormcoming #thepeak</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-display">
      <img />
      <p class="tags">#perfectbeach #whitesand</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that this just checks for the value of the `innerText` of the `p` tag.

Comment: thank you so much this helps a ton i would have never thought of putting the innerText to the p tag

Answer (score 0):

```
let images = document.querySelector('.thumb-display');
```

I think you're looking for `.querySelectorAll()`.
This would be a good place to start:

```
let images = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-display') ];
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all elements `.thumb-display` you have to use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

- `document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-display')`

And then you can do:

```js
const query = document.querySelector('#filter')
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset')
const thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-display')

query.addEventListener('keyup', () => thumbs.forEach(t => {
  const p = t.querySelector('p')
  t.style.display = p.innerText.includes(query.value) ? '' : 'none'
}))

reset.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  query.value  = ''
  thumbs.forEach(t => t.style.display = '')
})
```

```css
img {
  background: grey;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <form class="frm-filter">
      <div class="frm-group">
        <a class="reset hidden" href="#">Reset</a>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="filter" name="filter" placeholder="tag filter" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </nav>
  <section class="gallery">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Gallery</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#africa #mountain #road</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#palmbeach #distantpeaks</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#oceanbeach #mountainroad</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#lake #clearskies #onthewater</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#fallcolors #bridgecrossing #river</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#fallcolors #slowdown</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#falltrees</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#ontheroad #falldriving</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#mountainflowers #clouds #river</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#mountainlake #retreat</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#stormcoming #thepeak</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-display">
        <img />
        <p class="tags">#perfectbeach #whitesand</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```